# Additional information: Connection error: Trying to add unknown port '192.168.1.100'

Tags: c#, sqlanywhere

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=SAOLEDB.10;LINKS=tcpip(IP=192.168.1.100,Port=2638);ENG=dental;Persist Security Info = True; User ID = dba; PWD = sql");
    conn.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT tran_num FROM transactions WHERE tran_date > '2015-10-01'", conn);
    OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
     }
    reader.Close();
    conn.Close();

    if (Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

As the title suggests, I'm getting an error when attempting to connect to this server. The driver (Provider) works fine for a local database using the same server setup, trying to adjust the code to connect remotely to the same setup at a different location. This is an old SQL Anywhere 10 database and I've tried hard to find answers for this with no success so far.

Edit: I changed the string a little to reflect some suggestions, now just getting a new error: Additional information: Connection error: TCPIP requires a server name

Update: The syntax changes to LINKS seems to have progressed my attempts but now I'm having issues with the syntax it's looking for when searching for a server at that IP. Receiving an error: Additional information: Database server not found

This is the connection string in registry:
DBN=DENTSERV;DSN=DENTAL;UID=DBA;PWD=SQL

I've tried both ServerName= and ENG= using the DSN and DBN, also while having them in ' ' but still receiving that same error. Any thoughts?

Comment: the comma in `LINKS=192.168.1.100,2638` seems weird: maybe it require a colon `:`?

Comment: Without knowledge on this, is the 2638 number on the conn string the port number? If so, shouldn't it be marked with ':' instead of a comma? LINKS=192.168.1.100:2638

Comment: Shouldn't that be `LINKS=tcpip(IP=<IP>;PORT=<port>)`?

Comment: I have attempted with both the , and colon : with the same results. @Thomas - I added in the tcpip and getting a new error now: Additional information: Connection error: Unable to initialize requested communication links `LINKS=tcpip(<192.168.1.100>,<2638>)`

Comment: I should also mention I have no issues connecting to this server using a separate tool which generates this connection URL: `jdbc:sybase:Tds:192.168.1.100:2638?ServiceName=`

Comment: Please remove the `<` and `>`. These were just meant to be indicators for the placeholders. I also think I was wrong regarding the syntax. See the edited comment